# Count number of columns matching supplied parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I need to return any `Individual` where the count of any row column's matching a supplied parameter >= 3.

**Notes:** `Individual` has a number of 1:N child entities e.g. `PassportNumbers`, linked by `IndividualID` foreign key.  Parameter for these (`@PassportNumbers`) are supplied as a comma separated string (`'test01,test02'`).

**Current solution**

```
SELECT DISTINCT I.* FROM Individuals I
LEFT JOIN PassportNumbers PN ON PN.IndividualID = I.IndividualID AND (PN.Value IN (SELECT value FROM string_split(@PassportNumbers, ',')))
LEFT JOIN Forenames F ON F.IndividualID = I.IndividualID AND (F.Value IN (SELECT value FROM string_split(@Forenames, ',')))
LEFT JOIN LandlineNumbers L ON L.IndividualID = I.IndividualID AND (L.Value IN (SELECT value FROM string_split(@LandlineNumbers, ',')))
LEFT JOIN MobileNumbers M ON M.IndividualID = I.IndividualID AND (M.Value IN (SELECT value FROM string_split(@MobileNumbers, ',')))
LEFT JOIN UPRNs U ON U.IndividualID = I.IndividualID AND (U.Value IN (SELECT value FROM string_split(@UPRNs, ',')))
WHERE 
(       
    (SELECT 
        CASE WHEN I.Surname = @Surname THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN I.EmailAddress = @EmailAddress THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN I.MiddleName = @MiddleName THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN I.Alias = @Alias THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN @BirthDate IS NOT NULL AND I.BirthDate = @BirthDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN @DeathDate IS NOT NULL AND I.DeathDate = @DeathDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN PN.Id > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN F.Id > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN M.Id > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN L.Id > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN U.Id > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
    )
    >= 3
)
```

**Problem:** Query Performance

**Question:** Are there any improvements that can be made to the existing query or alternative solutions?

Comment: The subquery is going to be *awful* for performance, if I am honest. What are you trying to achieve with the above? Do you need the `DISTINCT`? Are you (ab)using it due to one to many joins in your `FROM`? If so, why not use an `EXISTS`? You don't return *any* columns from those `JOIN`ed table, so why `JOIN` to then? How many columns are there in the table `Individuals`?

Comment: NULLIF(@Surname, '') IS NOT NULL  Wont this NULLIF make the value '' so it will never be NULL.

Comment: Removing the `JOIN`s and replacing the relevant `CASE` statements with `EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM PassportNumbers PN WHERE PN.IndividualID = I.IndividualID AND (PN.Value IN (SELECT value FROM string_split(@PassportNumbers, ','))))` seems to be even worse in terms of performance..  Unless you mean something different by the above?

Comment: Without knowing the full requirement, I wouldn't like th guess what a *good* solution would be; all I can tell you right now is that it's bad.

Comment: `NULLIF(@Surname, '') IS NOT NULL` will always be true, there is no reason to have this

Comment: "I need to return any Individual where the count of any row column's matching a supplied parameter >= 3." is the full requirement in this case

Comment: There are 9 columns that belong to the table `Individuals`

Comment: `NULLIF` checks removed - original problem remains the same

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you are doing that will make this query slow.

You are trying to something that is complex -- check on a lot of criteria and then only pick results that go above a threshold.  Your question would be clearer if you stated this in the question

First you are getting comma separated values, it would better if these were table parameters then you would not have to convert them.  However, I expect there are not many of them (often just one or two phone numbers for example), so what you want to do is query those results first with a CTE and then join to the CTE -- this might improve performance depending on your indexes.

Speaking of indexes, that could make a big difference.  Please post what indexes you have and we can give suggestions about improvements.

```
WITH PNFilter AS (
  SELECT x.IndividualID
  FROM PassportNumbers x
  JOIN string_split(@PassportNumbers, ',')) SS ON SS.Value = x.Value
), FFilter AS (
  SELECT x.IndividualID
  FROM Forenames x
  JOIN string_split(@Forenames, ',')) SS ON SS.Value = x.Value
), LLFilter AS (
  SELECT x.IndividualID
  FROM LandlineNumbers x
  JOIN string_split(@LandlineNumbers, ',')) SS ON SS.Value = x.Value
), MNFilter AS (
  SELECT x.IndividualID
  FROM MobileNumbers x
  JOIN string_split(@MobileNumbers, ',')) SS ON SS.Value = x.Value
), UFilter AS (
  SELECT x.IndividualID
  FROM UPRNs x
  JOIN string_split(@UPRNs, ',')) SS ON SS.Value = x.Value
)
SELECT DISTINCT I.* 
FROM Individuals I
LEFT JOIN PNFilter PN ON PN.IndividualID = I.IndividualID
LEFT JOIN FFilter F ON F.IndividualID = I.IndividualID 
LEFT JOIN LLFilter L ON L.IndividualID = I.IndividualID 
LEFT JOIN MNFilter M ON M.IndividualID = I.IndividualID 
LEFT JOIN UFilter U ON U.IndividualID = I.IndividualID 
WHERE 
(        
  CASE WHEN NULLIF(@Surname, '') = I.Surname THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
  CASE WHEN NULLIF(@EmailAddress, '') = I.EmailAddress THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
  CASE WHEN NULLIF(@MiddleName, '') = I.MiddleName  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
  CASE WHEN NULLIF(@Alias, '') = I.Alias THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
  CASE WHEN @BirthDate = I.BirthDate  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
  CASE WHEN @DeathDate = I.DeathDate  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
  CASE WHEN PN.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN F.Id  IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN M.Id  IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN L.Id  IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN U.Id  IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
) >= 3
```

As you can see, I cleaned up the code a lot, removed extra select statements and such.

--

Note, Value and Values can be a reserved word on some platforms so it is not a good column name.

Answer (score 0):

Try if preprocessing `PassportNumbers`, etc will speed up the query

```
with pnPrm as(
   SELECT value FROM string_split(@PassportNumbers, ','))
),
..
UPRNsPrm as (
   SELECT value FROM string_split(@UPRNs, ',')
)
select I.* 
from Individuals I
left join (
   select IndividualID, count(flag) count1
   from (
      select IndividualID, 'PN' flag
      from PassportNumbers PN 
      join pnPrm on pnPrm.Value = PN.value
      
      union  -- distinct IndividualID + flag
      
      ..   
      select IndividualID, 'UPRNs' flag
      from UPRNs U ON U.Value = UPRNsPrm.value
   ) t
   group by IndividualID
) t2 on t2.IndividualID = I.IndividualID
where coalesce(t2.count1,0) + 
        CASE WHEN I.Surname = @Surname THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN I.EmailAddress = @EmailAddress THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN I.MiddleName = @MiddleName THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN I.Alias = @Alias THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN I.BirthDate = @BirthDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  +
        CASE WHEN I.DeathDate = @DeathDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  > 3
```

Consider also making `@PassportNumbers` / `pnPrm`, etc TVP instead of csv string.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this and tell us how it works:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT I.* FROM Individuals I
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT SUM(X.CONTROL)
FROM (
SELECT 1 CONTROL FROM PassportNumbers PN WHERE PN.IndividualID = I.IndividualID AND ','+@PassportNumbers+',' LIKE '%,'+PN.Value+',%' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 CONTROL FROM Forenames F WHERE F.IndividualID = I.IndividualID AND ','+@Forenames+',' LIKE '%,'+F.Value+',%' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 CONTROL FROM LandlineNumbers L WHERE L.IndividualID = I.IndividualID AND ','+@LandlineNumbers+',' LIKE '%,'+L.Value+',%' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 CONTROL FROM MobileNumbers M WHERE M.IndividualID = I.IndividualID AND ','+@MobileNumbers+',' LIKE '%,'+M.Value+',%' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 CONTROL FROM UPRNs U WHERE U.IndividualID = I.IndividualID AND ','+@UPRNs+',' LIKE '%,'+U.Value+',%'
UNION ALL
SELECT CASE WHEN @BirthDate IS NOT NULL AND I.BirthDate = @BirthDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CONTROL
UNION ALL
SELECT CASE WHEN @DeathDate IS NOT NULL AND I.DeathDate = @DeathDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CONTROL 
) X
HAVING SUM(X.CONTROL)<=3
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).